# Get Transaction Additional Info in magento refund

Tags: php, magento, transactions, payment-gateway

> I am making a custom payment gateway and i have in the capture payment in magento when a payment has been through:
>
> ```
> $payment->setTransactionAdditionalInfo                     
>            (Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAILS,array
> ('TransactionGUId'=>$result['transaction_guid'], 'TransactionId'=>$result
> ['transaction_id'],'Messages'=>$result['messages']));
> ```
>
> which writes the payment transaction additional information .
>   I need to get in the refund these additional informations to send them to the payment Gateway.
>   I tried

```
           $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment_transaction')->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq' => $payment->getOrder()->getEntityId()))
     ->addAttributeToFilter('txn_type', array('eq' => 'capture'))
            ->addPaymentIdFilter($payment->getId());


           $transaction = $collection->getAdditionalInformation('transactionId');
            $transactionGUId = $collection->getAdditionalInformation('transactionGUId');
```

> but it returns an error.